# How to call a ffmpeg command only for the last file of a folder?

Tags: ffmpeg, batch

Here is my command, it's to cut he last 20 seconds of a video.

```
ffmpeg -y -sseof -20 -i  record.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 27 -preset veryfast output.mp4
```

It works perfectly, but I would like to have to same command, for cutting the last 20 seconds of the last file created with .mp4 extension in the folder. Thanks if you can help me.

Edit :  OS is Windows

Comment: You mean the most recent file? See [Get most recent file in a directory on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1015678)

Comment: `ffmpeg` can't do this on its own. As this is more of a batch/cmd/powershell question I suggest making the title more accurate; something like *"How to get the last file in a folder in batch/cmd/powershell?"* You might increase your chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this batch file:

```
@echo off
FOR /F " tokens=*" %%i IN ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:c *.mp4') DO (SET a=%%i) 
ffmpeg -y -sseof -20 -i  %a% -vcodec libx264 -crf 27 -preset veryfast output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

To get and use the latest file in your directory directly/immediately, do not set variable, use your loop variable `%%i` instead:

Use **`dir`** by order **`/o:`** inverse **`-`** date **`d`** == **`dir /o:-d /b *.mp4`**

- To use this file with your `ffmpeg` command in bat/cmd file:

```all-bat
@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0" & for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /o:-d /b *.mp4')do (
ffmpeg -y -sseof -20 -i "%%~i" -vcodec libx264 -crf 27 -preset veryfast "%~dp0output.mp4" & goto :next
)

:next
```

- To use in command line:

```all-bat
2>nul del /q /f .\output.mp4 & for /f %i in ('dir /o:-d /b *.mp4')do if not exist .\output.mp4 ffmpeg -y -sseof -20 -i "%~i" -vcodec libx264 -crf 27 -preset veryfast output.mp4
```

- If you no longer use commands, you can use `goto: EOF` instead of `goto: Next:`

```all-bat
@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0" & for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /o:-d /b *.mp4')do (
ffmpeg -y -sseof -20 -i "%%~i" -vcodec libx264 -crf 27 -preset veryfast "%~dp0output.mp4" & goto :EOF)
) 
:next
```

Comment: Thank you very much